# Asp.Net Core - Not Able to Upload Files From Dropzone JS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using asp.net core 2.2 with dropzone js.

I am trying to submit a form along with the files contained in dropzone js.

I have an input file field (can be hidden or not hidden). I want to assign dropzone files to this field and submit it. But the Forms field is always null.

Here is the code:

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Add(ViewModels.Photo model)
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; // this is also empty
    ....
}
```

MVC Model:

```
public class Photo
{
    ...

    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Photos" method="post" id="addForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dropzone">
        <input asp-for="Files" type="file" multiple hidden/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var e = "#addForm",
var t = new Dropzone(e, {
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
    uploadMultiple: false,
    autoProcessQueue: false
});
t.on("addedfile", function (o) {
    $("#Files").files = t.files;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get things working and it was a minor fix.

I changed below code

```
$("#Files").files = t.files;
```

to

```
$("#Files").files = t.hiddenFileInput.files;
```

`t.files` is an array of files being captured by dropzone where as `t.hiddenFileInput.files` is an `FileList` object of files being captured by dropzone.

The `$("#Files").files` is also an `FileList` object that's why `t.files` was not working due to type mismatch.

Now it submits form fields along with files with default submit mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a different method signature of the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //handle file.InputStream
}
```

This example shows uploading the files one by one: https://gillesleblanc.wordpress.com/2017/01/25/integrating-dropzone-js-into-an-asp-net-mvc-site/

Comment: There are additional input fields as well on the HTML page. That's why it is getting complicated for me

Comment: You might have two forms, one for the edit fields and another just for the files. The IDs of uploaded files could be returned when the file is uploaded and incorporated into the form with the fields and then posted with this form.